# How to apply additional EXIF fields to JPEGs in Android

Tags: android, camera, metadata, jpeg, exif

I'm writing an app where I'd like to add the direction of the camera view to the image taken. I've seen the [android.media.ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class, but it looks limited to only a few fields.

The [exif 'standard'](http://www.cipa.jp/english/hyoujunka/kikaku/pdf/DC-008-2010_E.pdf) defines GPSImgDirection and GPSDestBearing which look like the ones I want, but they're not defined with the ExifInterface class.

Is there any way of applying them to an image (with or without ExifInterface)? I'm prepared to write my own jpeg header parsing, but would really like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: did you try use "GPSImgDirection" string instead of static string from  ExifInterface when you using getAttribute(String tag)? getAttribute("GPSImgDirection") ?

Comment: No, but I should at least try it. I assumed that since the docs defined the string values it wouldn't accept anything else...

Comment: ok, tried it and it doesn't throw an error but it won't save the attribute. Looking at the source of ExifInterface shows that it's just doing its defined tags and ignoring anything else. I wonder if I can extend that class with my definitions though...

Comment: So the only possibility is to fine java exif implementation, port it to android(maybe there is one allready ported) and use it

Comment: extending almost worked - could write the attribute (although value looks odd), but can't read it. Could be close though.

Comment: JPEG header parsing is quite simple, the problem is that Exif is not part of the JPEG standard. Parsing Exif is a pain in the a**.